# how to resign keyBoard as a firstResponder from a textView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to resign the keyboard from the text view as a first responder.I want as soon as user hits the return key after editing in a textView the keyboard should resign.But I am not sure how should I do this???

Answer (score 2):

Hope this code helps to you.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{    
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

use UITextViewDelegate protocol and yourTextViewName.delegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

If your class is set as the delegate for that textview just do the following in your class code

```
- (void)textViewTextDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: but as i press the return key it just comes to the next line

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text

{
  if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
  [textView resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
}
```

> yourTextView.delegate=self;
>   Also add,  in '.h' file
>
> If you didn't add "if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])" you can't edit

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the text field has been set as a delegate and add the following code to your implementation file:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[myTextField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
```

}